# How to autofocus on current element of list (Android App)

Tags: java, android, listview, netflix

When I scroll the Netflix **"Coming Soon"** list, the app always **"focuses"** on the current element. Does anybody know how they do that? Maybe a vertical `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 0):

First u need to set selection  `myListView.setSelection(position);` as current one

Then u can request focus to that listView using  `myListView.requestFocus();` Most probably  it will behave as u expected